# unbalanced dataframe from long to wide

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like data_long:

```
data_long<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2))
colnames(data_long)<-c("treatment","rolls")
data_long[,1]<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1)
data_long[,2]<-c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)
```

I want to rearrange data_long to data_wide:

```
data_wide<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol=4))
colnames(data_wide)<-c("Treatment1","Treatment2","Treatment3","Treatment4")
data_wide[,1]<-c(6,6,6,6)
data_wide[,2]<-c(6,6,6,NA)
data_wide[,3]<-c(6,6,NA,NA)
data_wide[,4]<-c(6,NA,NA,NA)
```

I think the problem is, that I have unbalanced data. Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_long %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  mutate(unique_id = 1:n()) %>% 
  spread(treatment, rolls)
```

In order for `spread` to work properly, each row within the treatment groups needs to have a unique identifier.

Comment: Hei Mark, thanks for your answer. I have tried something similar already, however it does not work. This message occurs: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows. The problem is that I have a different amount of people in the treatments (23 in T1, 20 in T2, 19 in T3, 17 in T4), therefore it is difficult to create an identifier column...

Comment: Can you post some data which reproduces the error you get when you use gather / spread?